# How to decrease the space after figures

Tags: spacing

I want to reduce the space between Figure description and text.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is a top float (you don't say) then the space is the length parameter `\textfloatsep` which will be set by your document class but you can change with `\setlength`.