# Reduce gap between a figure and a paragraph

Tags: spacing, floats

I put 2 figures side by side as follows:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfigure[a long sentence a]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{figures/cells_time_23h29.eps}}
  \subfigure[a long sentence b]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{figures/zones_time_23h29.eps}}
\end{figure}
```

I don't know if I accidentally added spaces somewhere, it seems that there is a big white gap between these 2 figures and the paragraph below them.

However, I really would like to save space. Could anyone tell me if there is something I am doing wrong? Otherwise, is there a way to manually reduce the gap?

Besides, if I remove the labels for the subfigures `a long sentence a` and `a long sentence b`, the gap does not reduce. So I guess there is always space reserved for the labels of the subfigures?

Comment: Please construct a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) from `\documentclass...` until `\end{document}`. If you use the `graphicx` package I recommend using it in the MWE as follows `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`

Comment: You are putting a `subfigure` inside a `subfigure`. Also there is an open `{%`.  Which package do you use? `subcaption`?

Comment: @HarishKumar sorry I should have deleted one more line, just updated OP...

Comment: @SoftTimur -- Try changing `\subfigure[...]{...}` into `\subcaptionbox{...}{...}`. Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26522/34618 for reducing spaces.

Comment: @SoftTimur Check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101121/how-to-decrease-the-space-after-figures). I've compared your example with `[H]` alignment (`float` package) to a simple figure and caption with `[H]` alignment. They look like the same that way.

Comment: @SoftTimur Did any of the above tips help?